# how to integrate zend framework with cakephp 2.0 for the search optimization?

Tags: zend-framework, cakephp, search

Is it possible to integrate the zend framework with cakephp 2.0?
I want to have search features in the cakephp 2.0 web-application using zend framework.

Answer (score 1):

Define what your requirements for a search are. This questions is to generic.

There is a search plugin for CakePHP by the way: [CakeDC Search](https://github.com/cakedc/search)

[A plugin to create search indexes](https://github.com/neilcrookes/searchable).

Maybe it's going to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have made search page in my web-application. It's like the keyword search type and retrive data from the multiple tables. But sometime i get time-out message of cakephp since database is quite large so i was thinking to have the search features by indexing. Is it possible to do in cakephp by integration of zend Framework or some kind of making plugins.
I check the reference and its quite helpful too.

Comment: How many records and tables are you searching? This sounds more like a bad database design. But check this plugin https://github.com/neilcrookes/searchable or you can also use sphinx for indexing, there a plugin for sphinx too afaik, just google it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution for actual searching is to use Apache Solr. It's a search engine that can be used with any framework through its web service interface.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

It is based upon the same library Zend Framework Search uses called "Lucence", expect Apache Solr exposes "Lucence" functions as web services. Very nice and easy to use.